# Unable to hit breakpoints Google Chrome Dev tools while working with local files

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, osx-elcapitan

Chrome dev tools has a very cool feature that lets you map the source code the web site you are debugging against local files stored on the machine. This gives you the ability to change code on chrome dev tools and have those changes reflect in your locally stored files. This is such a great feature because you can make edit and debug directly from the dev tools. Unfortunately on the mac the breakpoints are not hitting. If I make changes to the files they do reflect however, the breakpoints do not hit.

OS X El Capitan

10.11.3 (15D21)

Chrome:

Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

This works fine on windows 10 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue by browsing to the sources tab. Navigate to the file trying to debug from the site you are navigating. In my case it was under localhost/.....

Once you find the file you want to debug there should be an option at the top of the file to establish mappings. Follow the instructions and map it to the local file. Once you do this you will be able to set breakpoints of the local file you have mapped. In my case establishing the mapping for one file seem to have mapped the rest of the local files under the mapped folder.